# SQLServerException when using CallableStatement.setObject(int,Object)?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Quick question, why am I getting the below exception when using the following code;

Note this is using Java to call into MS SQL Server 2008 R2 using stored procs.

```
Connection con = getDataSource().getConnection();
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("countrySelect(?)");
cs.setObject(1, "GB");
cs.execute();
```

Results in;

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:390)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:340)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:322)
```

Where is this "@P0" coming from? Is this the Java memory reference? How come its not converting to SQL types properly?

I get the same thing if I can to;

```
cs.setString(1, "GB");
```

Stored Proc code is as follows (not written by me);

```
DECLARE @dbid INTEGER;
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(125);
DECLARE @prcName NVARCHAR(125);

SET @dbid = DB_ID();
SET @dbName = DB_NAME();
SET @prcName = 'usp_countrySelect'

IF dbo.ufn_Admin_countryExists(@countryCode) = 1 

   SELECT countryCode
    , countryName
    , nationalVerificationPrice 
    , vatCharged 
    , VATPercentage 
    , sortingPrecedence 
 FROM dbo.country
WHERE countryCode = @countryCode ;

ELSE

RAISERROR  (  N'ERROR: A country with countryCode %s does not exist - proc Name:%s, database ID:%i, the database name is: %s.'
            , 16 -- Severity
            , 1  -- State
            , @countryCode -- First subbed argument
            , @prcName -- Second subbed argument
            , @dbid -- Third subbed argument
            , @dbName -- Fourth subbed argument
       );

END
```

Comment: Could you please post the source code for your procedure too? The syntax error is in the procedure itself

Comment: Edited original to include stored proc code

Comment: Thanks for the update. The above looks like the procedure body, `@P0` is not part of it. `@P0` could be a parameter, though, could you maybe include the procedure's signature? i.e. `CREATE PROCEDURE countrySelect(@P0... )`

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Admin_countrySelect @countryCode NVARCHAR(10)

Comment: And what about this procedure: `dbo.ufn_Admin_countryExists` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, rather lame error to an un-obivous problem if you ask me;

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("countrySelect(?)");
```

Does NOT work, instead use;

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call countrySelect(?)}");
```

Difference being the word "call" and the enclosing { } brackets.